# DNN indexer fails with 2sxc content modules

Tags: dotnetnuke, 2sxc

On a recent DNN/2sxc installation, the DNN index functions fail with a GeneralException: "The given key was not present in the dictionary."

The stack error is:

> Message:Search: Error while indexing module 458 on tab 50, portal 1
>
> StackTrace:
>
> at
>
> > ToSic.SexyContent.Environment.Dnn7.DnnBusinessController.GetModifiedSearchDocuments(ModuleInfo
> >     moduleInfo, DateTime beginDate) in
> >     C:\Projects\2sxc-dnn742\Website\DesktopModules\ToSIC_SexyContent\2sxc
> >     Dnn\Environment\Dnn7\DnnBusinessController.cs:line 89 at
> >     DotNetNuke.Services.Search.ModuleIndexer.IndexSearchDocuments(Int32
> >     portalId, ScheduleHistoryItem schedule, DateTime startDateLocal,
> >     Action`1 indexer)
>
> InnerMessage:The given key was not present in the
>   dictionary.
>
> InnerStackTrace:
>
> > at System.ThrowHelper.ThrowKeyNotFoundException() at
> >     System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary'2.get_Item(TKey key) at
> >     ToSic.SexyContent.ContentGroup.get_Template() in
> >     C:\Projects\2sxc-dnn742\Website\DesktopModules\ToSIC_SexyContent\ToSic.Sxc\SexyContent\ContentGroup.cs:line
> >     70 at
> >     ToSic.SexyContent.ContentBlocks.ModuleContentBlock..ctor(IInstanceInfo
> >     instanceInfo, Log parentLog, ITenant tenant, IEnumerable`1
> >     overrideParams) in
> >     C:\Projects\2sxc-dnn742\Website\DesktopModules\ToSIC_SexyContent\ToSic.Sxc\SexyContent\ContentBlocks\ModuleContentBlock.cs:line
> >     82 at
> >     ToSic.SexyContent.Environment.Dnn7.Search.SearchController.GetModifiedSearchDocuments(IInstanceInfo
> >     instance, DateTime beginDate) in
> >     C:\Projects\2sxc-dnn742\Website\DesktopModules\ToSIC_SexyContent\2sxc
> >     Dnn\Search\SearchController.cs:line 55 at
> >     ToSic.SexyContent.Environment.Dnn7.DnnBusinessController.GetModifiedSearchDocuments(ModuleInfo
> >     moduleInfo, DateTime beginDate) in
> >     C:\Projects\2sxc-dnn742\Website\DesktopModules\ToSIC_SexyContent\2sxc
> >     Dnn\Environment\Dnn7\DnnBusinessController.cs:line 85
> >     Source:ToSic.Sxc.Dnn

Recycling the application pool revives the application but the problem will occur again and again.

I found these solutions:

```
Delete the DNN index files and reindex    
Remove and give back rights to the application pool to the index files    
Convert the site in English then set it back in French
```

but nothing works. The problem only occurs with 2sxc modules (basic contents) and not with other modules (HTML for exemple).

Any idea to solve that?

Environment: DNN 9.1.1 2SXC 9.23

Comment: I often get a similar error when swapping between application pools on my development machine - Is this happening in production or without swapping between app pools?

Comment: In production and I'm not swapping the app pool. I only have one site with only one app pool.

Answer (score 2):

Just fyi: this really seems to be an issue - we're working on it, check out I'm guessing this is related to https://github.com/2sic/2sxc/issues/1564 and https://github.com/2sic/2sxc/issues/1561

Note that this is fixed in 9.31, and we'll release 9.32 with some more fixes.

Comment: I've had these issues 3x today whilst working on a local site soon to be pushed to production. I've just installed v09.31.00-pre1 as this is the latest at time of writing. I'll report back here if I encounter the errors again. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The good news is that I don't have the problem anymore...
The bad news is that I don't know why...

As a really bas scientist, I did several actions at the same time and one of them (or in conjonction) solved the problem. What I did :

- upgrade to 2sxc version 9.30
- set the recycling time of the application pool to 10080 minutes (7 days)
- unchecked both static and dynamic cache in IIS
- installed the Windows Server updates (and rebooted the server)

Also, I'm connecting to the server using RDP. When I start my connection, I now uncheck the use of the local printers, the clipboard, and the local drives (in fact, I don't bind any local resources to the distant server). I realized that there were errors because the driver of my local printer was not installed on the remote server. Not sure it has to do with it but as I don't need these bindings anymore, I deactivated them.

Next step is to try to set back the cache and set a shorter time for recycling the application pool.

If I find something, I'll update this post.

Answer (score -1):

I imagine this has to do with the reference to a path that does not exist on the server.  We have been experiencing this every night after our nightly backup runs.  Cycling the AppPool brings it back (as you have indicated), but we plan to upgrade to 9.30 (which was just released today - https://github.com/2sic/2sxc/releases).  May the 4th be with you!

By the way, we noticed 9.23 was marked as a "Pre-Release", so this may have not been so smart to use this version?  :)

Comment: Note that this is fixed in 9.31, and we'll release 9.32 today or tomorrow with some more fixes.